# How to create an adjustment layer in one line of code? (AE scripting)

Tags: javascript, scripting, after-effects

So, i have a button that creates a solid and then makes it an adjustment layer

var adjLayer = comp.layers.addSolid([1.0, 1.0, 1.0], "Adjustment Layer", comp.width, comp.height, 1);
adjLayer.adjustmentLayer = true;

And when i press ctrl+z it makes only one step back, so it turns an adjustment layer back to solid layer.

Are there any way to combine this steps in a one action, so when i press ctrl+z the layer disapears?

im a poo poo in coding so idk

i want something like this but working
var adjLayer = comp.layers.addSolid([1.0, 1.0, 1.0], "Adjustment Layer", comp.width, comp.height, 1).adjustmentLayer(true);

Btw i ve seen some AE scripts that create an adj layer in one step so when i press ctrl+z the created layer disapears

Comment: *i ve seen some AE scripts that create an adj layer in one step* - Why not use them?

Comment: they also have buttons i dont need and theyre compiled so i cant just delete

Answer (score 0):

everyting between these two is one history event

app.beginUndoGroup("History event name");

app.endUndoGroup();